QGIS 3.38.1-1 embedded symbols not loading
New unwanted behaviour in 3.38.1-1 (code version 3d4177afc6): embedded symbology from imported KMLs are ignored.  This happens in both upgraded and new projects.
I am an admin on Trailforks, and download KMLs of trails in our riding areas to import into QGIS for planning purposes.  In previous versions of QGIS (including 3.38.0) the symbology (trail difficulty rating - black, blue, green, etc) for the trails would be given for all trails.
In 3.38.1, that symbology is ignored, and I must categorize the trails by difficulty myself.  Is this an intended change, or a bug?

This is what it used to look like when importing KMLs in 3.38.0 (this is of course a screenshot of 3.38.1, but showing the trails coloured as they used to be in 3.38.0 and earlier):

